# How to change the number of elements visible based on a user input in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm very new to Angular and I'm trying to get my program to change the number of rectangles visible based on the value of a slider that the user can change. For example, if the slider is set to '2' then there should be 2 rectangles shown on the page. I am working in Angular 14

I tried using ngFor as shown below to display the rectangles, but that just made it to where no rectangles were visible. In the below code, the rectangle tag is a separate component that just has a border and background color. The rectangle-grid tag is a way to organize how they are laid out inside and for this example the rectangles will just be stacked onto of each other. The numRectsSlider is a slider that the user can change and has a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 4

```
<rectangle-grid>
   <rectangle *ngFor="let rect of numRectsSlider.value"></rectangle>
</rectangle-grid>
```

Should I create all 4 rectangles and make them become visible/invisible as needed or should I do something like what I have above and not create them until they are needed?

Comment: You might want to share a bit more of your coding, in regard to the interaction you're planning to develop~

Comment: Does <rectangle> display outside of ngFor loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch case - since it's only four items based upon your description.  I'm making the assumption that your value is a number.

```
<rectangle-grid>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="numRectsSlider">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="1">
      <rectangle></rectangle>

    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="2">
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="3">
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="4">
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
      <rectangle></rectangle>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</rectangle-grid>
```

Comment: you might want to also listen for changes with a ChangeDetectorRef.

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor need to use a Iterable [see](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor)

a solution is to create a Array in the ngFor like this:

`<rectangle*ngFor="let item of [].constructor(numberOfRect)"></rectangle>`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the suggested answer from @cfrancoi.
Another solution would be to define a method in your component that returns an Array based on the actually selected slider value.

```
get rectSliderCount(){
  return new Array(this.numRectsSlider.value);
}
```

```
<rectangle-grid>
   <rectangle *ngFor="let rect of rectSliderCount"></rectangle>
</rectangle-grid>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using this method as it will get me more familiar with how Angular does its thing, but I'm having trouble getting it working. The problem I'm having is the numRectsSlider is not known in the typescript file and when I tried to bring it in with document.getElementById(numRectsSlider.value) it says HTMLElement doesn't have the 'value' element. Do you have an idea on what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based in the [Netanel Basal's range directive](https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1)

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[range]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class RangeDirective {
  _range: number[];

  @Input()
  set range(value: number | number[]) {
    this.vcr.clear();
    const valueArray = typeof value == 'number' ? [0, value] : value;

    const [from, to, step=1] = valueArray;
    const range: number[] = [];
    for (let i = from; i < to; i += step) range.push(i);

    range.forEach((num) => {
      this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl, {
        $implicit: num,
      });
    });
  }

  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef, private tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

You can use

```
<rectangle *range="numRectsSlider.value"></rectangle>
```